# How do I add post history to my wordpress.com blog?

Tags: wordpress.com

I'm using the Penscratch theme for a wordpress.com blog, and it doesn't seem to have post history.

I've looked through the blog-customization options, and I didn't find how to add this. I suspect it's hiding in there, but I've not been able to find it.

Comment: I am afraid this is not the place for this kind of [questions](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You are better off at the [theme's support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/theme/penscratch). Or maybe (but not likely) at the http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ site.

Comment: the wp.se site is for developers or hosters, this is just the web-app. So... I'll head to the forum you mention. Thanks.

Comment: @marikamitsos: This question is absolutely on-topic here.

Comment: @AlE. ok, thanks. I'll keep that in mind, and if I get an answer somewhere else, I'll come back to post it here.

Comment: Do note that questions about the self-hosted WordPress would be out of bounds here. Configuration, installing a theme, customization, etc. (Usage from the perspective of a user would be okay.)

Comment: @marikamitsos The theme support forum said it was off-topic there. :)

Comment: @AlE. and Almo. My mistake. I misread. I thought the post was about WordPress.**org**. Sorry about the confusion. Glad you worked it out though.

Comment: Hahah yeah... .org. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "Customize" under "Widgets" there's a thing called "Recent Posts". Add that, and bingo.